# existing frameworks for a questionnaire style app for web and mobile

Tags: node.js, frameworks, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a project where I can work on rails or nodejs to build a questionnaire style app, where the admin can post questions, check for top score, average scores and the user can take the questions. I have a basic knowledge on both rails and node but not good enough to build  a fully functional app. I am working on it, but would like to know any good frameworks that would help me make the building process quicker, either in rails or nodejs. I did come across devise and surveyor in rails. please do suggest good starting points or other frameworks that would be useful in both rails or nodejs.

Comment: what part of the actual app are you looking for help. You could probably do it just fine in either. I'd bet this app is already written and open-sourced.

Comment: @timpone I have not started working on the app. I am looking for suggestions that would reduce the build time. I am a novice in both rails and nodejs, so looking for suggestions that would be easy and fast to learn and implement. I will look into the opensource app as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about using sth like https://github.com/patocallaghan/questionnaire-js

This is a purely (client) javascript framework (using MVC frameworks underneath, like Angular).

On server-side one would only need to validate and save the data.